# Prefab like objects in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, skscene

Unity uses prefab files (prefabricated files) which are game objects that can be templated in the project with defined properties. This is especially useful when you want to position your objects in your scene directly per drag & drop (visually) without using any code.

My question is if something like this is possible in iOS and Xcode 6, since for now I only found out that you can drag and drop images into the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean drag'n'drop 3d objects in Xcode the answer is no. Xcode provides wysiwyg methods to work with the UI and even data models but this does not extend to three dimensional constructs; it is a coding tool, not a level editor!
To build 3D applications using Xcode and related SDKs the usual approach is loading scene data created using 3rd party software such as Blender, then programmatically traverse the graph to associate behaviors. There is support for doing this at SDK level. Look at the Apple examples to find out more, as your knowledge will not immediately transpose from Unity to Xcode: the building blocks are essentially the same, but the approach to putting them together is not.

Comment: Thx! It doesn't have to be 3D. I'm working with SpriteKit only. I can drag&drop textures into my scene editor in Xcode and change some properties of that texture -> like collision behavior and it's masks. But it's just a texture. What I would need is to add (drag) my own objects with custom properties. 
But I found a workaround. When the game starts, I just iterate over all children of the scene and check their names. If a child name matches a name of a predefined object from my object factory, I replace the child with my own object. For now, it's good enough but I wonder about the performance

Comment: Oh, looks like Xcode improved! The only overhead to your solution (more of a solution than a workaround) is that of deleting the texture. With ARC it should be fine - better than doing it in a GC environment. So, I think you will be fine.

Comment: You'r right :), ARC has it's bright points too. Thx for the help!

Comment: Obviously old but you can now associate a class with an SKNode within the editor. Override init:coder and encode:code to manage the node once initialized and do things like set variables such as child nodes.